# Webpack works fine but webpack dev server does not run app gives console error

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I am new to Vuejs Webpack configuration. I am trying to run vuejs app using dev server but unable to. Webpack command is running fine and I am able to build the app successfully and its running fine but when I am trying to run app with dev server its opening up the url on browser itself but throwing console error unable to trace whats going on.

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: `js/[name]_[hash]_bundle.js`,
    chunkFilename: `js/[name]_[chunkhash]_chunk.js`,
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 4300,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: ["vue-style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: { name: "vendor", chunks: "all" },
  },
  resolve: {},
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
    }),
  ],
  devtool: "source-map",
};
```

This is the error I am getting while running webpack-dev-server command,
[image]

As you can see here its loading the js bundle files properly here in index.html
[image]